# Minimum difference between non-equal elements in integer array

Tags: python, numpy

I do have a list with integer arrays where every element has value <= 100. I need to figure out the smallest difference between non-equal elements for every array. So far I have the following (`item` represents one array):

```
unq  = numpy.unique(item)
mind = numpy.amin(
        (numpy.append(unq, [999]))
       -(numpy.append([-999],unq))
       )
```

Using `numpy` I first get sorted array of unique elements. After adding high positive number at the end and high negative number at the beginning I substract these two arrays and get minimum value.

Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is ok except that instead of using `numpy.append` you would better use `np.diff`, like `np.diff(np.unique(a))`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.random.randint(0,100,size=50)

In [4]: np.unique(a)
Out[4]: 
array([ 0,  2,  3,  5,  7,  8, 15, 18, 20, 22, 23, 27, 30, 31, 32, 33, 37,
       38, 42, 43, 45, 48, 49, 57, 59, 62, 65, 70, 74, 75, 76, 78, 79, 80,
       83, 84, 88, 91, 93, 94, 96, 98])

In [5]: np.diff(np.unique(a))
Out[5]: 
array([2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 7, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 8,
       2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2])

In [6]: np.diff(np.unique(a)).min()
Out[6]: 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not mention it, but there is only 1 unique element in some arrays. For such cases this results in error, because I can't use empty array (result of `np.diff()` as an input to `min()`. Is there something like `coalesce` in Python?

Comment: I used `numpy.amin(numpy.diff(numpy.append(unq,999)))` where `unq=numpy.unique(item)`

Comment: @twn08 in this case you could do it in 2 steps: 1) `diffs = np.diff(np.unique(a))` and then 2) `min_dist = diffs.min() if diffs else 0`. You could also assign `None`, like `...if diffs else None` if you prefer.